# How to add a blank item at the start of a list in a combobox?

Tags: vb.net

I am using this loop to generate a list of months

```
i = 1
        Do While i <= 12
            ListedMonths.Add(New ListedMonth(i, MonthName(i)))
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        Return ListedMonths
```

but i also want to show a blank option at the top before January.

i have tried adding `ListedMonths.Add(New ListedMonth("","Select"))` before the while loop

but when running my vb.net application, i get nothing listed in the combo box. when i remove the above line, it lists Jan-Dec fine

Comment: I'm not sure what your ListedMonth objects are, but did you want `ListedMonths.Add(New ListedMonth(0,"Select"))`?

Comment: Once you've checked your parameter type as Blackwood mentionned (integer vs string), if it still doesnt work please post the code for ListedMonths, and eventually the code that uses the list.

Answer (score 0):

You create a `ListedMonth` item by passing an *Integer* and a *String* to its constructor. So I think the first Parameter expects an *Integer*, but you pass an empty *String* in your attempt. That's why you should try the following statement to add your *Select* item:

```
ListedMonths.Add(New ListedMonth(0, "Select"))
```

If it does not work: it would be helpfull to see your `ListedMonth` type and know the technology you use (WPF, WinForms, ...).